# How to implement separate authentication for two applications sharing the same backend in Express.js?

Tags: express, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have 2 react apps and an expressjs backend. Both frontend apps have cookie based authentication with express-session middleware. the following domains corresponds to each app:

- app1: app1.example.com
- app2: app2.example.com
- backend: back.example.com

and the following is the cookie configuration:

```js
const CookieConfig = {
  name: "session_id",
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    domain: ".example.com",
    path: "/",
    signed: true,
  },
  resave: false,
}
```

How can I achieve separate authentication for two applications (app1 and app2) that share the same Express.js backend? I want to prevent users logged into one app from accessing the other and if users are connected to both apps they should stay connected. The issue arises when transitioning between apps, as the browser sends cookies from both, leading to unintended sharing of authentication states. What is the recommended approach to ensure each app maintains its distinct authentication and cookies while using the same backend?